# How to show "Search Display Controller" using a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a weird requirement, or at least something I have never done before... I have a `UITableView`, the header of that table is a `UISearchBar`. If you tap on that searchbar the "Search Display Controller" shows up and let you search... But now I need to remove that searchbar and call the "Search Display Controller" from a button.

The problem is that if I remove the SearchBar when I call (from the button):

```
   [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES]
```

I can't see the UISearchBar on top of the View.

I have no idea how to fix this... I have already tried:

- `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil` in the viewDidLoad and when touching the button I set the UISearchBar as the table header again... it looks ugly and the animation is not smooth at all.
- hide the searchbar and show it when the button is pressed. (i get an empty space in the tableview's header) and the animation is really bad, because the `UISearchBar` gets first displayed in the header and the it's moved up to the top of the view...

Any help will be more than welcome!! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realise that you have tried that, but thats the way we do it and it works:

We add the UISearchBar into the view (not the table view). That being said you can't do that if you are using a UITableViewController. You have to add the tableView to a UIViewController. Then we link it via an Outlet to the Controller and then set it to hidden in viewDidLoad:

```
self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
```

Then create a selector to show the searchBar again:

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
  self.searchBar.hidden = NO;

  [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

  [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: One addition: You can hide the searchbar under the NavigationBar, that way it does not pop up when you unhide it.

Comment: that was useful! I did this.Thanks a lot